# APK does not upload to Fabric Crashlytics

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have a react-native application, whose android apk I want to upload to Fabric Crashlytics and used this guide https://medium.com/komenco/beta-testing-your-react-native-android-application-with-crashlytics-483c7e66a423 . In the terminal, I run:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

And everything seems to go well, I get:

```
:app:crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
Uploading /.../theapp/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk to Crashlytics...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

However, the app never gets uploaded to Fabric Crashlytics. What could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Paul from Fabric here. Are you able to see your app in the dashboard? If not, could you try building and running your app manually?